# Cocos2d-iphone sprite moving in wrong direction

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

cocos2d version 1.0.1 
xcode 4.6.2
iphone 6.1 simulator
deployment target 4.3

I have written simple code for my game, in which I am trying to make a sprite move left by 10 points when i touch on the sprite.
The problem is when I touch on the sprite it moves left and sprite bounding box moves down, ie the sprite is moving on -x axis but sprite bounding box is moving on -y axis. please help me solve this problem I dont know If there is some problem with the coordinate system or Device Orientation settings

```
    -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

     CCSprite *mysprite = (CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:1];

     if (CGRectContainsPoint([mysprite boundingBox], touchLocation)) {
        [mysprite runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(-10,0) ]];
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

before if condition I added this code

```
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:touchLocation];
```